# Get index of speceific characters in a char array [JAVA]

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm coding a calculator and i want to find operators index in a char array . My code right now looks like:

[image: looking of the code:]

I get an error on the if statement as it expects a char array and not a char.

How can i make this work or what i have don bad?

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=`...

Comment: i still get an error as it expects a chararray instead of a char.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing char array you can directly store the String in the array like

```
ArrayList<String> texto = new ArrayList<String>();
texto.add(text);
```

and then you can search operators index using String indexOf function.

So your final code will be something like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> indexOperator = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String> texto = new ArrayList<String>();
texto.add(txt);
for(int i = 0; i<texto.size; i++){
for(char operator:operators) {
if(texto.get(i).indexOf(operator)!= -1){
    indexOperator.add(texto.get(i).indexOf(operator));
}
}
}
```

The other ways to shorten this code is

1. Put all the operators in array and then match it through loop.
2. Use regex here

**Code updated for single string**

```
ArrayList<Integer> indexOperator = new ArrayList<Integer>();
char[] operators={ '+', '-', '*', '/'};
for(char operator:operators) {
if(txt.indexOf(operator)!= -1){
    indexOperator.add(txt.indexOf(operator));
}
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks! but then i dont really need to store it in an ArrayList as i just got a single string?¿?

Comment: Yeah if you got a single string then definitely no need of array list.

Comment: Man I really apreciate it, im initiated to this, thanks!

Comment: If it helps, appreciate if you can accept it as an answer.